# Some sequence convergence problems

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove that any sequence {$x_n$} that satisfies $|x_n-x_{n+1}|<=\frac{1}{2^n},n\in\Bbb{N}$ is convergent.
Prove that a sequence that satisfies $x_{n+1}-x_n\to0$ is not necessarily convergent.

Comment: 1 - prove that $|x_n-x_1| \le 1$, then prove that sequence can't have more than one partial limit. 2 - prove that $x_1=1, x_{n+1}=x_n+{1 \over n}$ diverges.

Answer (score 0):

(a) Suppose that $n>m$. Then
\begin{align*}
|x_n-x_m|&=|x_n-x_{n-1}+x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}+\ldots+x_{m+1}-x_m|\\
&\le|x_n-x_{n-1}|+|x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}|+\ldots+|x_{m+1}-x_m|\\
&=\sum_{j=m}^{n-1}|x_{j+1}-x_j|\\
&\le\sum_{j=m}^{n-1}\frac1{2^j}.
\end{align*}
The series $\sum 2^{-j}$ converges. Hence, $\sum_{j=m}^{n-1}2^{-j}$ can be made arbitrarily small by choosing large $m$ and $n$. It follows that the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence and converges.

(b) As a counterexample, consider harmonic series, i.e. $x_n=\sum_{j=1}^n j^{-1}$. We have that $|x_{n+1}-x_n|=1/(n+1)\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, but the sequence $\{x_n\}$ diverges.